# ngrx effects custom operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Is it possible (how?) to implement custom operator which would look at action's payload and if there is operator (switchMap, concatMap,..) present use it otherwise use some chosen default op.?

It would be great for libs which generate store (eg. from swagger). They also generate effects and they could give opportunity to lib users to override default operator used for API calls.

Comment: Operators can't investigate the chains they're part of by themselves

Comment: why, is there a way to make this happen? Wrap around Observable.create, Subject or custom operator that behaves like switchMap, concatMap, mergeMap,..?